4K frame buffer mod - Run application in 4k resolution
I have an Android TV BOX, this version is OS11, I want to run and APP or APK with 4k Resolution 3840x2160,
The default frame buffer is limited to HD 1920x1080, I would like to modify frame buffer to do this,
is the limitation purely the OS? does newer OS allow for this...
or better question, is modifying firmware required to make this happen, is there anything out there, thanks in advance.
Any application natively designed for 4s, reset at HD at run of operation

Is your tv box hardware is capable of rendering 4k resolution? By default frame buffer in many Android TV boxes is set to HD (1920x1080) due to hardware or firmware limitations. Achieving 4K resolution might require hardware that supports 4K output and modifications to the firmware.

Its not a Hardware limitation, however is it a firmware limit, the device CAN display and play MOVIES and PHOTOS in 4 and 8K however, applications are limited to 1080,
Firmware or OS has a default framebuffer that I want to overwrite, Im currently running OS 11, wondering if limites of 4k apps get unlocked in higher OS like 13 or 14? this device is a H98Pro using Mail G52. Im actually not sure if limited framebuffer is in OS or Firmware.... anyadvice will be greatly appreciated

For Modifying Framebuffer > In that case you have below options : 1. Modify build.prop File using adb command    2. Use Custom ROMs and flash the OS.  3. Check firmware updates from the manufacturer if available update it  3. Update your os from 11 to 12 or above    4. Change HDMI settings > Settings > Display > HDMI Mode and set it to 4K ....... But before all that you have to understand the limitations of OS and firmware.

Hi Bob, does Android OS 12 have Native support for 4k Apps or 4k Frame buffer as a default>? thanks

Consider contacting to manufacturer's guide book or their technical support. As mine TV is Android 10 which is 4 years old and support 4k. So it's totally dependent on manufacturers hardware and firmware.

I have tried they only confirm Framebuffer is set to dh, however they say using Android ADB I can modify framebuffer somewhere... Im still not sure where frame buffer setting is, possibly framebuffer setting in OS somewhere? thanks

I have posted the way to change the Frame Buffer, take a look and if you have any additional question or error you are getting you can ask in the comment of  the answer itself.

@Steven Raz as per your question

Im still not sure where frame buffer setting is, possibly framebuffer setting in OS somewhere?


Below the steps to change frame buffer :
1. Verify Current Framebuffer Settings
Use ADB (Android Debug Bridge) to access the system.
adb shell getprop | grep framebuffer
2. Modify build.prop File
Ensure you have root access.
Access build.prop: Located in /system/ or /system/vendor/.
adb pull /system/build.prop
Modify the framebuffer resolution.
persist.sys.display-density=3840x2160
ro.sf.lcd_density=160

Push modified build.prop :
adb push build.prop /system/
adb reboot

Reference link :

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/graphics/opengl/FrameBuffer


Thankyou Bob, this will be interesting, will device overhear or simply run normal.

Do you mean device overheat ?
